# Is there a Linux system command that can be called to change the arbitration scheme set for PCIe devices?

Tags: linux, pci-express

When probing our PCIe boards we see that everything in our system is set to a Fixed arbitration scheme. From my readings, this scheme is left up to the vendor (Which I'm assuming is our OS).

I would like do some experimenting with different arbitration schemes to see how it effects our DMA rates.

For context, we have a duel socket motherboard with 6 PCIe slots, 3 for CPU1 and 3 for CPU2. One of our boards is on a slot for one CPU and the other board is on a slot of CPU2. They are identical boards with identical software running. We DMA data over from system memory to the memory located on our boards. The DMA rate varies between the two boards where one is typically always faster than the other board by a significant rate.

Our PC vendor confirmed that other customers are seeing this discrepancy where one board seems to be given a higher priority over another on different PCIe slots.

Is there a way to tap into this Port VC Capability Register to change the arbitration scheme?

If I didn't list the correct register that would adjust the arbitration scheme, could you tell me which is the correct one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that arbitration is the issue here, and adjusting it's settings requires board support as well as kernel modification. The vc extended capability interface is handled in part in the linux kernel here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pci/vc.c

I've written drivers for custom PCIe boards in Linux, and the algorithm for routing traffic between boards has not shown itself to be an issue in the past, unless you have a very unusual use case - extremely long transfers with near real time latency requirements (in which case you shouldn't be using PCIe). 

What can directly impact this type of performance, and is far more readily addressed, is the topology of the bus the itself, although the impact is usually barely measureable.

On the machine, run the lspci command as:

```
lspci -tv
```

Which will show you a tree view of the PCIe interfaces and the route to the CPU(s) that they take. With most processors you will have some slots that go directly to the CPU and others that go through a bridge chip (see [Intel x99 chipset](http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/feature-understanding-intel-x99-high-performance-computing-platform)

These bridges introduce latency and the possibility of slower throughput. The CPU direct is specifically configured for high performance devices such as video cards. To your initial point, deep in the processor micro code there may be optimizations which further degrade the bridged links. To dig deeper in evaluating the performance and routing of the PCIe slots continue in the sysfs.

Under /sys/bus/pci/slots/ will be a list of the pci slots (physical) in your system. In it is a virtual file which associates bus address <----> physical
slot.

Under /sys/bus/pci/devices is a list of all devices (this is where lspci gets it's info).

Going through each of the devices you can see all of the information exposed by the kernel on them, the drivers associated with them, the CPU associated with the device (on multiple CPU system), among other things.

Edit - I didn't mention some obvious things that i assume you have ruled out, but just in case:
1. Do the different slots both have at least as many lanes as the boards?
2. Is there a spec discrepancy- eg board is pcie 3, one slot is 3 and the other 2?
3. Have you discussed this concern with the board vendor and/or the driver developer beyond them acknowledging iy? They may be aware of some random errata regarding it

If you provide specific details I can provide specific advice.

Beyond looking at the topology (is the faster device on a direct CPU path, while the other is not), not knowing the type of chipset / CPU you are using, I can only offer general advice, but three areas that I would start looking at are:

Interrupt Latency: If the interrupt for board is associated with a CPU/core that is handling other devices with a high interrupt rate, you will take a performance hit. Is there other kernel context heavy lifting going on on that core? watch /proc/interrupts to see what other kernel modules are using that CPU for it's interrupt handling and the count/rate at which they occur. Try adjusting the CPU affinity for that device in /proc/irw ... smp_affinity. smp affinity is a mask, if you had 8 cores and didn't specify anything, it would be set to FF (8 1's). If you set it to, e.g. 0x02, that will force Core 2 to handle the IRQ. Unless you know you are addressing a specific issue, forcing these changes can easily make things worse.

Interrupt support: Take a look and see if one of the devices is using MSI-x or MSI interrupts, while the other is using a standard (electrical) interrupt. Sometimes bridges don't support a boards MSI implementation (MSI means message signaled interrupt - rather than an electrical interrupt its just a packet that gets sent over the bus itself). If a device typically uses multiple interrupts but has to operate with only a single one due to this, it can be hard to detect unless you are directly looking for it, and can cause performance issues.

Characterize performance. There are many tools in the kernel to collect performance data. The one thing that they all have in common is that they are poorly documented and generally unsupported. But with that said, I would look at using Ftrace to characterize the dma transfers from each board, and the IRQ latency for each. You can get statistical information as well as specific details on outlier events. You can start looking into that here: http://elinux.org/Ftrace

In general I strongly discourage mucking about in very low level settings without as complete as possible an understanding of what you are trying to correct (not the symptoms to correct, but the underlying root cause). 99% of the time you will end up turning 'knobs' for the sake of it, but without understanding why or what the original problem is, how can evaluate the effectiveness of a given setting (both immediate and in terms of long term stability).

I heavily use ftrace for general kernel debug and highly recommend it. If you want things abstracted a bit, there are wrappers around ftrace that claim to make it easier to use, but I found the additional abstraction just muddies the water - trace-cmd, kernel shark, etc. If you are on a red hat system you can look into systemtap - not the same thing but can provide similar data (and it's well supported).

Comment: Thanks for this in depth response. 
We have two custom boards that are PCIe 1.0 x8 with our own driver that communicates with it. There is also a third party network card occupying another PCIe slot that supports PCIe 3.0 x8.
The motherboard looks to have the X99 chipset so I'll read through the link you provided.

I'll provide more information shortly

Answer (score 0):

While additional levels of PCIe bridging (switching) can effect latency response and throughput, the differences in performance due to this cause my experience are not that great.   Much more typical, and almost certainly the issue you are seeing, is that the user space application, and/or the device driver memory buffers allocated for your different HBA cards is in fact being allocated all on one of the two CPU, in this case on CPU1.   As a result, all DMA from or to memory initiated by the device connected to CPU2 is slower than that connected to CPU1, because all the involved system memory is actually being hosted on CPU1 in your particular workload.   For application memory, this is common, and there is not much that you can do about it.  (For fancier applications, some have switches based on environment variables or command line options that can effect where they allocate the memory from, and some applications will allocate different memory, on different CPU, for different processes.  But those applications are few, most do not provide such control.)

The device driver (assuming it is in your control here) can take steps to allocate its memory in a NUMA aware manner, and specifically allocate driver buffers on a CPU node that is closest to your I/O device.  This takes additional, documented steps in the device driver, but again few device drivers take these additional steps.  (Some do).  If this is done, and IF (and only if) the device driver actually copies data from user to kernel buffers (now NUMA allocated), then you should see identical performance between two HBA cards for DMA.   (The overall transaction rate may still be slower to one or the other, because the user space to kernel space copy will still be slower for one of the two cards, because the application's memory (the original source of copying) is typically all allocated on one particular CPU node (in your example CPU1), and will take longer to copy from user space to kernel space on CPU2 than it takes to go from user to kernel space buffers on CPU1.  All multi-socket systems suffer from this issue, but for some systems the problem is worse than others based on the speed of their inter-CPU interconnect (such as QuickPath, UPI, Hypertransport) etc.

Even when a device driver has gone to the trouble of allocated node specific memory, that does not always help.   First, often times, a driver may be doing direct user space to device DMA (zero copy DMA) rather than copying into kernel space buffers first.   In this case, there are no associated kernel buffers that can be allocated in a node adjacent manner.   Second, even when there is node specific memory in the device driver, and even when that memory is used by the device driver, you still see the differential delay in copying from user space to kernel space (the near HBA to near kernel memory copy is faster), the far HBA (CPU2 here), and far CPU2 device memory if it exists is slower.   In such case, this just "moves" the problem from unequal DMA speeds, to instead be "unequal" user space to kernel space buffer copies.  The DMA times will equal out, but the transaction times (that include the user to kernel copy) will still be unbalanced.  This later reason is one of the reasons why a lot of device driver writer's don't bother allocating node specific memory.  (The other main reason is simple ignorance.)

In either case, the time penalty for the difference in memory access speed is almost certainly much greater a factor than the time penalty from a difference in PCIe switching delays.

As an end user, there is pretty much nothing you can do.  As a device driver writer, you can utilize NUMA aware memory allocation techniques in your device driver.  Depending on the workload, sometimes this helps quite a bit, and sometimes it doesn't do much at all.

Unless you can get BOTH the device driver AND the source application to allocate their memory in a NUMA aware fashion (and for the application, this is often difficult or impossible because of the manner in which the data is factored) you cannot defeat this uneven speed difference problem.